# Python substring in string when parts of the substring is not consequential

Tags: python, string, search

Say this is my `string`: `http://www.test.com/1/page/`
And this is my `sub_string`: `www.test.com/2/page/`

Now if I run

```
sub_string in string
```

The result will obviously be `False` because `2` is not in the `string`. However, I don't care about that part. The only parts I care about are `www.test.com` and `page`. I want only these parts to be checked, and don't care about what's in between them. How can I perform a search in that way, so the results would be `True`?

Comment: You might also find this interesting [Approximate string search in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175554/approximate-string-search-in-python)

Comment: Try splitting out the prefix and suffix of interest from your string using `.split()` or `partition()` and then use `.startswith()` and `.endswith()` to check for a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex`.

```
import regex as re
test_string="www.test.com/2/page/"
len(re.findall(".*www\.test\.com\/[0-9]\/page\/",test_string))>0
```

**Output**:
True

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```py
import re
all_locs = re.findall('www\.test\.com/[0-9]+/page/', source_string)
```

This will return all locations where the substring appears in. An empty list means it didn't appear

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use:

```
if substring in string.lower():
    print("Exists")
else:
    print("Does not exist")
```

or `regex`:

```
import re
for match in re.findall('www\.test\.com/[0-9]+/page/', str):
print(match)
```